# Image and Kernel of composition of two homomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, function-and-relation-composition, group-homomorphism

I have just showed that the composition of $a * b$ of two homomorphisms $a,b$ is a homomorphism. However, what can I say about the image and kernel of $a*b$, in terms of $a$ and $b$? Is there something special about this image and kernel now that there is a composition of two homomorphisms?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Set}[1]{\left\{ #1 \right\}}$
First of all, I would suggest you use $a \circ b$ as the standard symbol for composition.

Then note that if $b : G \to H$ and $a : H \to K$ are morphisms of multiplicatively written groups, say, you have
$$
\ker(a \circ b) = \Set{g \in G : a(b(g)) = 1}
= 
\Set{g \in G : b(g) \in \ker(a)}
=
b^{-1}(\ker(a)).
$$
Here $b^{-1}$ is not the inverse of $b$, which need not exist, but it is the map that takes a subset $L$ of $H$ to the subset
$$
b^{-1}(L) = \Set{ g \in G : b(g) \in L}
$$
of $G$.

As to the image, you have simply
$$
a \circ b(G) = a(b(G)),
$$
so the image of $a \circ b$ is the image under $a$ of the image $b(G)$ of $b$. This is true at the level of sets.

Comment: So in other words, your $b^{-1}$ is the preimage of b?

Comment: @Divide1918, yes.